# How to get location of label in list in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

[image]

1. I want to get the uid using name
   for eg: someFunctionToFindUidOfName('Akt') //should return uid = 0, but don't know how to get that i am new to dataFrames please explain the answer
2. I also want to checkif dataFrame has username and password if it has it will print "user found!"

please answer in 1 and 2 differently and please explain as much as u can in simple terms

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

First to construct a DataFrame with the same format as yours:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'password' : ['1234', '4567', abcd']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.index.name = 'UID'
print(df)
```

which will give the output below. Notice that the first column is different - it is the index as in your data.

```
      name password
UID                
0    name1     1234
1    name2     4567
2    name3     abcd
```

Then code to get an uid and test it.

```
def get_uid(want_name):
    result = df[df['name'] == want_name]
    if result.empty:
        return('No such user from get_uid ' + want_name)
    else:
        return (want_name + ' uid is ' + str(result.index.item()))
              

print(get_uid('name2'))
print(get_uid('name4'))
```

How this works is that to select the row with the query name and if it exists get the index item (that is under the UID heading). As it is a number it is converted to a string. So it gives:

```
name2 uid is 1
No such user from get_uid name4
```

Next use a similar approach to check for a user and get the password:

```
def check_user(want_name):
    result = df[df['name'] == want_name]
    if(result.empty):
        return ('No such user from check_user ' + want_name)
    else:
        return (want_name +' User found with password ' + result['password'].item())
           

print(check_user('name2'))
print(check_user('name4'))
```

which gives results:

```
name2 User found with password 4567
No such user from check_user name4
```

The part that might need explaining is `result = df[df['name'] == want_name]`. What this does is select from the DataFrame that part where the expression inside df[ ] is True. Then the result can be used to give the part of the data of interest. To check both user and password then:

```
def check_user_pass(want_name, try_pass):
        result = df[df["name"] == want_name]
        if result.empty:
            return 'No such user'
        else:
            real_pass = result["password"].item()
            if real_pass != try_pass:
                return 'No such user *'
        return 'User found'
    
print(check_user_pass('name1', '1234'))
```

Comment: thanks you it worked howeer i wanted to check both username and password (like if entered username and passsword is in the dataframe only then it says found!) but thats fine

Comment: I added a function to check both user name and password. Hope you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the uid from the name just simply use that:

   ```
    dataFrame[dataFrame['name'] == 'Akt']['uid']
   ```
2. Do you mean if **name** and **password** columns exist?

   ```
    if 'name' in dataFrame.keys() and 'password' in dataFrame.keys():
        print('user found')
   ```

Hope it helps